# Display Search Results in Modal Dialog/Box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I can't seem to get my modal box to display the results of a search, I can submit the form and the modal box will appear, I've tried echoing my variables in the modal box but nothing shows. I've tried putting the Search script, and script in the modal box. Nothing. I've tried it with almost every Modal box I could find, so it's not the modal boxes I'm just not doing something right. I just know I'm tired, my eyes hurt, and I'm just about to give up doing this. I just don't want the page to refresh when searching, because it clears all the values the user in puts to search for a model id. In order to create a creature, you must have the model ID which aren't easy to find I'm trying to provide my copy of the model ids to be searched through. Please. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**THE FORM**

```
// My form
    <form name="Form2" method="get" action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" id="Form2">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox19" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:80px;width:191px;height:35px;line-height:35px;z-index:0;" name="name" value="" class"rounded">
    <div id="wb_Text25" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:134px;width:58px;height:34px;z-index:1;text-align:left;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;">Entry ID:</span></div>
    <input type="text" id="Editbox20" style="position:absolute;left:20px;top:153px;width:191px;height:35px;line-height:35px;z-index:2;" name="entry" value=""class"rounded">
    <div id="wb_Image2" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:5px;width:221px;height:31px;z-index:3;">
    <img src="images/modelid.png" id="Image2" alt=""></div>
    <div id="wb_Text24" style="position:absolute;left:18px;top:46px;width:227px;height:34px;z-index:4;text-align:left;">
    <span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Arial;font-size:15px;"><br> Name:</span></div>

    <input type="submit" id="Button1" onclick="$('#jQueryDialog1').dialog('open');return false;" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:269px;top:187px;width:96px;height:25px;z-index:2;">// What activates the Modal Box

    </form>
```

**The Modal Box**

```
//Modal Box itself
<div id="jQueryDialog1" style="z-index:3;" title="This is the title">
//Modal Box Content where I want to display Search results.
</div>
</div>
```

**My Script:**

```
 // Modal Box Script
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       var jQueryDialog1Opts =
       {
          width: 554,
          height: 367,
          position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window },
          resizable: true,
          draggable: true,
          closeOnEscape: true,
          autoOpen: false
       };
       $("#jQueryDialog1").dialog(jQueryDialog1Opts);
    });
    </script>
```

**My Search Script:**

```
  <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['name'], $_GET['entry'])) {
        try { 

        $host = "xxxxxx";
        $user = "xxxxxxxx";
        $password = "xxxxxx";
        $database_name = "xxxxxxxx";
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(
        //PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ));

        $conditions = array();
        $oemSearch = $_GET['name'];
        $oempnSearch = $_GET['entry'];
        $min = 1;
        $oemLen = strlen($oemSearch);
        $oempnLen = strlen($oempnSearch);

        if ($oemSearch == "" && $oempnSearch == "") {
         echo "You must enter a Name or Entry ID";
         exit;
        }
         if ($oemSearch != "" && $oemLen < $min) { 
         echo "You must enter an Entry ID of atleast 1 Character.";
         exit;
        }
         if ($oempnSearch != "" && $oempnLen < $min) { 
         echo "You must enter at least 3 P/N characters.";
         exit;
        }
        if ($oemSearch != "" && $oempnSearch == "") {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from creature_template WHERE name LIKE '%$oemSearch%' ORDER BY entry LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
        //$query->bindValue(1, "%$oemSearch%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($oemSearch == "" && $oempnSearch != "") {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from creature_template WHERE name LIKE '%$oempnSearch%' ORDER BY entry LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
        //$query->bindValue(1, "%$oemSearch%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        if ($oemSearch != "" && $oempnSearch != "") {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("select * from creature_template WHERE name LIKE '%$oemSearch%' OR entry LIKE '%$oempnSearch%' ORDER BY entry LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
        //$query->bindValue(1, "%$oemSearch%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        // Find out how many items are in the table
        $total = $dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM creature_template ")->fetchColumn();

        // How many items to list per page
        $limit = 10;

        // How many pages will there be
        $pages = ceil($total / $limit);

        // What page are we currently on?
        $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
            'options' => array(
            'default'   => 1,
            'min_range' => 1,
            ),
        )));

        // Calculate the offset for the query
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

        // Some information to display to the user
        $start = $offset + 1;
        $end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);

        // Bind the query params
        $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        // Do we have any results?
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            // Define how we want to fetch the results
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $iterator = new IteratorIterator($stmt);

           // Display the results
        echo "<table class='views-table' border=1>";   
              echo "<tr class='tblheader'><th bgcolor=#00CC00>Name</th><th bgcolor=#00CC00>Entry ID</th><th bgcolor=#00CC00>Model ID</th></tr>";
            foreach ($iterator as $row) {
              echo "<tr class=odd views-row-first1><td><a href=http://wowhead.com/npc=";         
                echo $row['entry'];
                echo "></td><td><b>";
                echo $row['entry'];
                echo "</a></td><td><b>";
                echo $row['modelid1'];
                echo "</td></tr></b>";
            }
             echo "</table>"; 


        } else {
            echo '<p>No results could be displayed.</p>';
        }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo '<p>', $e->getMessage(), '</p>';
        }}
        ?>
```

Comment: you need jquery/ajax for that - for starting http://api.jquery.com/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ is the answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ajax at all? Remove your `onclick` from your button and try:

```
    $("#Button1").click(function(){
    var name = document.getElementById("Editbox19"); 
    var entry = document.getElementById("Editbox20"); 
    var jQueryDialog1Opts =
    {
    width: 554,
    height: 367,
    position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window },
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    autoOpen: false
    };

        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php?name="+name+"&entry="+entry,
            type: "GET",
            success:function(data){
                    $("#jQueryDialog1").dialog(jQueryDialog1Opts);
                    $("#jQueryDialog1").html(data);
            },
            error:function (){
                alert("Error!!! Please refresh the page and try again!");
            }
        });
    });
```

I assumed your search script is in a php page named "search.php". Change it accordingly yup.

Comment: I added the script right above the form, and tested, nothing happens. D: Much appreciated tho!

Comment: did you replace it with your own script where you have `// Modal Box Script`? Can you have a look at your console and let me know what error you're getting?

Comment: I replaced my script yes. What do you mean my console? No error's are being thrown.

Comment: Alright great. Make sure they are wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){` as well. If you are using chrome: _Right click > Inspect element > Console_. You see anything there before/after clicking submit?

Comment: I put $(document).ready(function(){ before  $("#Button1").click(function(){ is that right?

Comment: yes and make sure you're closing them as well. You should really tell me what you see in your console if you're seeking for help! Otherwise I can't guess/assume things :(

Comment: Javascript Console Errors say: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < and SyntaxError Unexpected identifier

Comment: It says this line has Unexpected Identifier
            // url: "search.php?name="+name+"&entry="entry, //

Says the "?" at error404.000webhost.com/?:1

Comment: Here's my site if you'd like to check it out, trinity-creator.com

Comment: please remove your button and replace it with `<input type="submit" value="Search" id="Button1"/>`

Comment: also, did you actually put all your PHP codes in a separate page called "search.php"?

Comment: Yes all my php is in search.php as you requested, and alright I'll throw it on

Comment: Also, I updated the code, but you didn't change yours. Please note the line should be: `url: "search.php?name="+name+"&entry="+entry,`. you're currently missing a `+` before `entry`.

Comment: I could never get it working but I'm sure it's me. I must be too stupid to do this.

Comment: Nahhh don't you say like that. If I can code, so can you! :) You just had to delete your form action and method (as you have now only set a name for it), and that would have made it work. But anyways, what's there now is `XMLHttpRequest()` which I'd say is another good way to call your data. Take things simple when it comes to coding, and that'd do! :) All the bests!