# form targeted to a modal in bootstrap

Tags: php, modal-dialog

What I want is as below: when I submit the form, the result will show in the model.

But when I tested, the result showed in the page instead of the model.

```
<div id="fast-search">
<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="searchForm" target="#myModal" action="" method="POST">
<div class="pull-right">
    <input type="text" name="searchTypeValue" value="0" hidden />
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="input-group mycustom pull-right">
    <input type="text" name="searchTerm" class="form-control rounded-0" id="" placeholder="Please enter a search term..." />
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

```
<div class="modal fade bs-modal-lg" id="myModal" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" >
        <div class="modal-body" >
            <img src="../assets/global/img/loading-spinner-grey.gif" alt="" class="loading">
            <span>Loading... </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I know that using  tag can show a page in the modal, like below. 
But it cannot pass the element values (searchTypeValue, searchTerm) by using `<a>` tab.

How to achieve this?

```
<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" href="{{ url('/']}}">
<input type="button" value="Search" id="searchBtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-0" /></a>
```

Comment: You can do it with ajax, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955642/display-search-results-in-modal-dialog-box

Comment: Thanks. Using ajax can get simple result. But I need to show a html page in the modal.  I use laravel. the action is in the controller, and it returns a view(*.blade.php).